# How to transition to a new screen instantly

Tags: flutter

I want to create a transition immediately from one screen to another (no animation). However isInitialRoute generates an error due to an update to the Router widget. The suggestion is to use onGenerateInitialRoutes but I am not sure how to implement it.

The flutter design doc recommends this:
Routes & RouteSettings
Currently, the only way to add a Route to the history stack without playing its entrance animation is to mark it as an initial route in its RouteSettings. The declarative API requires that routes can be added without animation at any time. This is useful when the route is covered by another route and playing the animation simply doesn't make sense. To support this, a didAdd method is added to the Route interface. This method is called by the Navigator instead of didPush when the Route should just be added without its regular entrance animation. To simplify things, this new method will also be used to bring the initial route on screen. This makes the RouteSettings.initialRoute parameter useless and it will be removed from RouteSettings. This is a minor breaking change.

This is the code that is generating the error on isInitialRoute:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart'
show
    CupertinoApp,
    CupertinoButton,
    CupertinoPageRoute,
    CupertinoPageScaffold;
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart'
show
    BuildContext,
    Center,
    Column,
    Navigator,
    Route,
    RouteSettings,
    SafeArea,
    Spacer,
    Text,
    runApp,
    Widget;

Widget makeButton(BuildContext context, String routeName) =>
new CupertinoButton(
  onPressed: () => Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, routeName),
  child: Text('Go to \'$routeName\''),
);

Route generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
        case 'not-animated':
            return new CupertinoPageRoute(
                settings: RouteSettings(name: settings.name, isInitialRoute: true),
                builder: (context) => CupertinoPageScaffold(
                    child: SafeArea(
                        child: Center(
                            child: Column(
                                children: [
                                    Spacer(),
                                    Text('This is \'not-animated\''),
                                    makeButton(context, 'animated'),
                                    Spacer(),
                                ],
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            );
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

void main() {
runApp(
CupertinoApp(
    onGenerateRoute: generateRoute,
    initialRoute: 'animated',
    routes: {
    'animated': (context) => CupertinoPageScaffold(
          child: SafeArea(
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Spacer(),
                  Text('This is \'animated\''),
                  makeButton(context, 'not-animated'),
                  Spacer(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If You Want to just navigate your screen add this to your code

```
onTap: (){
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => yoursecondscreenname()),
                );
              },
```